# Code Igniter pagination does not return all the rows having the same parameters

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I'm relatively new in Code Igniter and I'm trying to use the Code Igniter pagination class for the first time. I'm trying to get some rows in my database table, depending on the state, lga and category selected by the user. These three are passed to the function as parameters. I have followed the process I found on SO and some other sites to implement pagination on the page, and it seems to work, except that it doesn't return all the rows that has the specified parameters.

This what I have:

**Model - Posts_model.php**

```
public function count_lga_cat_posts($state, $lga, $category) {
        return $this->db->get_where('lga_posts', array('state' => $state, 'lga' => $lga, 'category' => $category, 'display' => 'true'))->num_rows();
    }

    public function fetch_lga_cat_data($limit, $start) {
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        $this->db->order_by("id", "desc");
        $query = $this->db->get("lga_posts");
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
            return false;
    }
```

**Controller - Lga_posts.php**

```
public function selected_state_lga_posts_category($state, $lga, $category)
    {       
        //config for pagination
        $config = array();
        $uri_seg = 5;
        $config["base_url"] = base_url('state2/'.$state.'/'.$lga.'/'.$category); //as specified in routes
        $config["total_rows"] = $this->posts_model->count_lga_cat_posts($state, $lga, $category);
        $config["per_page"] = 3;
        $config["uri_segment"] = $uri_seg;
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '&nbsp;<a class="current">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';
        $config['first_link'] = 'Back to first page';
        $config['next_link'] = 'View more posts';
        $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous posts';
        $config['last_link'] = 'Jump to last page';
        $config['display_pages'] = FALSE;

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $page = ($this->uri->segment($uri_seg))? $this->uri->segment($uri_seg) : 0;
        $this->db->where(array('state' => $state, 'lga' => $lga, 'category' => $category, 'display' => 'true'));
        $data["results"] = $this->posts_model->fetch_lga_cat_data($config["per_page"], $page);
        $str_links = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $data["links"] = explode('&nbsp;',$str_links );     
        $data['state'] = $state;
        $data['lga'] = $lga;
        $data['category'] = $category;
        $this->load->view('posts/lga/selected_state_lga_posts_category', $data);
```

When I load this page, everything seems to work fine, the pagination links are working as expected, but some rows in the table are not pulled, even though they have the same parameters as the ones that were pulled and displayed. If I change per_page config to 1, the last page gives an error "invalid argument in foreach" or something similar. I wonder if it has something to do with my query, since I do not want to get all the rows in the table, but the ones that have the selected parameters i.e. state, lga and category.

Can someone please point out to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: looks like you dont get any more items thats why your foreach loop gives you an error on the last page..... in other words your query is counting differently from your pagination for example you have page 1, 2 and 3 .... on page 1 you mostlikely post the items of page 2 and on page 2 the items of page 3 and on the last page you dont have any items anymore

Comment: You need to define same query while fetching count and rows. Also you don't need to overhead the result with foreach loop. ```foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }```. Just write ```return $query->result();```

Comment: Ok, so what do i do to rectify the problem?

Comment: First print the count, and print all the results of the query. If you found that ```count  == row-count(query_result)``` then you are going correct. Please check and update here in comments.

Comment: @Kishor10d, i tried what you suggested, but this time, it pulls all the rows in the first page without regard for the specified number of posts per page (which is 3). I also noticed that the Next Page link just reloads the data in the previous page. It's the same across all the pages.

Comment: I noticed that the line $this->db->limit($start, $limit) has an effect on results. I really don't know how that works with respect to pagination. Care to explain?

Comment: `$this->db->limit(max_returned, starting_offset)` [Documentation here.](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#limiting-or-counting-results)

Comment: Please check for ```segment``` you are getting correct.